# Could I use (how) instead of(what) in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Well,can you imagine how the world would look like if nobody took out the trash?
[image]

Comment: No because you can't say 'how the world would like". Why do you ask?

Comment: You have to choose between ***how** it **looks*** or ***what** it **looks like*** (as with *That's **how** it **is*** and *That's **what** it **looks like***).

Comment: did not understand you

Comment: Note that "what the world would look like if nobody took out the trash" is an interrogative clause (embedded question). The meaning is "Can you imagine the answer to the question 'What would the world would look like if nobody took out the trash?'"

Comment: *Like* is a preposition; it takes a noun. In your sentence, *what* functions as a substitute for the noun. ***What** would the world look like?* — *The world would look like **a huge dump*** (for example). *How* can function as a substitute for an adverb. Since *like* is a preposition, the construction *like X* can be considered an adverbial phrase ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial#The_form_of_adverbials)). Therefore, to use *how* in your sentence, you'd have to replace the whole *like* phrase with it: ***How** would the world look?* — *The world would look **like a huge dump**.*